# Unable to connect DB2 databases having SSL certificate using Python script from local machine

Tags: python, ssl, db2

I'm trying to connect DB2 databases hosted on Azure linux sever using python script, but getting the below error. I can connect to the same database using the .jks file from my local machine using Data Studio client.

```
Already the path C: \Python37\ Lib\ site - packages\ clidriver\ bin in the system variable.
Even below paths are also added in PATH and LIB environment variable.
C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\clidriver\bin\icc64
C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\clidriver\bin
C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\clidriver\lib

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\\FilePath\Db2_conn_updated.py", line 8, in <module>
    import ibm_db
  File "C:\Users\<User_Name>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\ibm_db.py", line 17, in <module>
    __bootstrap__()
  File "C:\Users\<User_Name>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\ibm_db.py", line 16, in __bootstrap__
    imp.load_dynamic(__name__,__file__)
  File "C:\Users\<User_Name>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Script -

```
import urllib
import ibm_db
import ibm_db_dbi
import pandas as pd

driver = 'IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER'
database = 'DB_NAME'
hostname = 'SERVER'
port = 'PORT'
protocol = 'TCPIP'
uid = 'USER'
pwd = 'PWD'
security = 'SSL'
SSLClientKeystoredb = r'C:\Users\<USER>\XXXX\XXXX_Root_2021.jks'
SSLClientKeystoreDBPassword = 'SSL_PWD'

#SslServerCertificate=r'C:\PATH\XXX_Root_2021.arm';

dsn = (
    f'DRIVER={driver};'
    f'DATABASE={database};'
    f'HOSTNAME={hostname};'
    f'PORT={port};'
    f'PROTOCOL={protocol};'
    f'UID={uid};'
    f'PWD={pwd};'
    f'SECURITY={security};'
    f'SSLCLIENTKEYSTOREDB={SSLClientKeystoredb};'
    f'SSLCLIENTKEYSTOREDBPASSWORD={SSLClientKeystoreDBPassword};'
)

test_query = 'select * from SCHEMA.TABLE'
conn_engine = ibm_db.connect(dsn, '', '')
db_conn = ibm_db_dbi.Connection(conn_engine)

df = pd.read_sql(test_query, db_conn)
```

Comment: You cannot use a java keystore (jks file) with ODBC (python ibm_db uses odbc to access the database, it does not use jdbc).  Choose a different option, one of these three: (1) no keystore at all, vis SSLServerCertificate=...  (2) a keystore created and populated by IBM's GSKit, or (3) use the Microsoft-Windows keystore.  All these options are  documented on IBM's websites.

Comment: Hi, We have got the .jks and .arm file only from the DB2 DBA team and apart from that we have the .kdb file in the server where we have added the .arm files using the gsk8capicmd_64 -cert -add -db  command. I have tried using the .kdb file, that also didn't worked. Can you please help me with the option that I could try to connect. I have to connect with SSL certificates only.

Comment: "didn't worked" tells us nothing. To use `SSLServerCertificate` keywod with the arm file, please follow the documentation  https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=keywords-sslservercertificate   . The ARM file needs to be on the hostname where python is running, and to use the arm file in the connection string, you need both `Security=SSL;` and `SSLServerCertificate=/path/to/armfile;` (substitute your own path ), so remove SSLClientKeyStoreDB and SSLSlicneKeystoredbpassword  entries from the connection-string when you are using SSLServerCertificate keyword instead.

Comment: Getting below error now -
driver = 'IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER'
database = 'DB'
hostname = 'SERVER'
port = 'PORT'
protocol = 'TCPIP'
uid = 'USER'
pwd = 'PWD'
Security='SSL'
SSLServerCertificate=r'C:\Users\Uname\Root_2021.arm';

dsn = (
    f'DRIVER={driver};'
    f'DATABASE={database};'
    f'HOSTNAME={hostname};'
    f'PORT={port};'
    f'PROTOCOL={protocol};'
    f'UID={uid};'
    f'PWD={pwd};'
    f'SECURITY={Security};'
    f'SSLServerCertificate={SSLServerCertificate};'
)
Exception: [IBM][CLI Driver] CLI0157E  Error opening a file. SQLSTATE=HY507 SQLCODE=-99999

Comment: Please edit your question, as your symptom is now unrelated to your original symptom. The message is clear "CLI0157E Error opening a file", so the file is maybe missing, or has directory/path permissions , or is somehow incorrect, or your temporary directory is inaccessible/full etc.